# Interactive javascript inside a twitter bootstrap carousel fails

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to have a video and an interactive chart side by side and nothing seems to work,not even iframes

This is the link http://vz.comxa.com/v2/

This is the html

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                                    <div class="item active">
                                        <div class="col-md-1">
                                            <li data-target="#carousel-0" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-5">
                                        <iframe id="cr-embed-16000US5367000-economics-poverty-seniors" class="census-reporter-embed" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/embed.censusreporter.org/1.0/iframe.html?geoID=16000US5367000&chartDataID=economics-poverty-seniors&releaseID=ACS_2014_1-year&chartType=pie&chartHeight=200&chartQualifier=&chartTitle=Seniors+(65+and+over)&initialSort=&statType=percentage" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="300" style="margin: 1em; max-width: 300px;"></iframe>
<script src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/embed.censusreporter.org/1.0/js/embed.chart.make.js"></script>
                                        <div class="hard-margins pull-right">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                                            Item 1
                                        </div>
                                </div>
```

I got the embeddable chart from here http://censusreporter.org/examples/embed-charts/

How should i go about fixing this?.

Comment: Is the site changed? I cannot find the chart anymore

Comment: I was almost able to tell where the problem is

Comment: Nope,did not change. Just added some few css elements.

Comment: where is the chart now

Comment: there isn't, check yourself

Comment: now the blocks are not clickable anymore

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see from the actual version of the website, copy the following

```
    <div class="col-md-1">
                                        <li data-target="#carousel-0" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                                    </div>
                                    <script src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/embed.censusreporter.org/1.0/js/embed.chart.make.js"></script><div class="col-md-5">
                                    <iframe id="cr-embed-16000US5367000-economics-poverty-seniors" class="census-reporter-embed" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/embed.censusreporter.org/1.0/iframe.html?geoID=16000US5367000&amp;chartDataID=economics-poverty-seniors&amp;releaseID=ACS_2014_1-year&amp;chartType=pie&amp;chartHeight=200&amp;chartQualifier=&amp;chartTitle=Seniors+(65+and+over)&amp;initialSort=&amp;statType=percentage" style="margin: 1em; max-width: 300px;" width="100%" frameborder="0" height="380"></iframe>



                            </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-5">
                                        <p><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/D873dq1fpcQ" allowfullscreen="" width="400" frameborder="0" height="340"></iframe>
                                    </p>
                                        <div class="col-md-1">
                                            <li data-target="#carousel-0" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

and it will work.